# Unable to find css selector using BS4

Tags: css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape some data off of 
https://www.bose.com/en_us/locations/?page=1&storesPerPage=10
but am unable to using BS4's `css selector`.

Because of the many classes of the tag that I am trying to grab, I am using the `soup.select()` function. I can easily do this using other functions but I am curious why using this specifically does not work.

[image]

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.bose.com/en_us/locations/?page=1&storesPerPage=10'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

soup.select('div.bw__StoreLocation')
# returns []

soup.select('.bw__StoreLocation')
# returns []
```

However, when I `print(soup)` I can see that `.bw__StoreLocation` is in it.

Comment: Either use [this link](https://bose.brickworksoftware.com/locations_search?hitsPerPage=10&page=0&getRankingInfo=true&facets[]=*&aroundRadius=all&filters=domain:bose.brickworksoftware.com+AND+publishedAt%3C%3D1566079348663&esSearch=%7B%22page%22:0,%22storesPerPage%22:10,%22domain%22:%22bose.brickworksoftware.com%22,%22locale%22:%22en_US%22,%22must%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22range%22,%22field%22:%22published_at%22,%22value%22:%7B%22lte%22:1566079348662%7D%7D],%22filters%22:[],%22aroundLatLngViaIP%22:true%7D&aroundLatLngViaIP=true) to parse location from json or use ***selenium***.

Answer (score 0):

Data is dynamically added. The request url, as per comments, is found in network tab.

```
import requests

params = (
    ('page', '0'),
    ('getRankingInfo', 'true'),
    ('facets/[/]', '*'),
    ('aroundRadius', 'all'),
    ('filters', 'domain:bose.brickworksoftware.com AND publishedAt<=1566084972196'),
    ('esSearch', '''{
                    "page":0
                    ,"storesPerPage":15
                    ,"domain":"bose.brickworksoftware.com"
                    ,"locale":"en_US"
                    ,"must":[{"type":"range","field":"published_at","value":{"lte":1566084972196}}]
                    ,"filters":[]
                    ,"aroundLatLngViaIP":"True"
                    }'''
    ),
    ('aroundLatLngViaIP', 'true'),
)

r = requests.get('https://bose.brickworksoftware.com/locations_search',  params=params).json()
data = r['hits'][0]['attributes']
address  = ', '.join([data['address1'] , data['city'], data['countryCode'], data['postalCode']])
print(address)
```